# How do I code a toolbar in android which has a carousel?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I was making my app when I thought I'd look at other apps for inspiration, when I came across this toolbar implementation.

[image: Toolbar with carousel]

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It is using FragmentStatePager which uses fragment for its implementation. 
 The menu has been set up and aligned using ActionMenuView.  Tablayout is also being used for the category